# Why QGIS/PostGIS makes Sliver / small polygon when using erase (difference) tool unlike ArcGIS (QGIS vs ArcMap)?

Tags: erase, slivers, st-difference, tolerance

When erasing b polygon from a, sliver(or small) polygons occured along the a polygon boundary in QGIS(3.4.5).
But ArcMap(10.3) does not make any slivers at all. I don't know which difference between two program exists.
I am struggling not to make any polygons and to know the reason. But, I cannot find any issues.

1. Both are not ring-self intersection polygons (st_isvalidreason)
2. Real Gaps are not shown.

I perhaps considered 'Tolerance issue'.. but I have no idea...

[image]
[[image]

[image]

Comment: Additionally, any ideas for the same problem using postgresql ?

Comment: I would guess there's some default tolerance setting that differs between the two. From the image, it appears that the two are not perfectly identical geometries, so I would expect slivers to occur. Can you confirm whether or not these polygons are identical?

Comment: It's completely same without the part (at 22 o'clock) . And a result of symmetrical difference generates empty polygon which means both are same (both QGIS and ArcGIS).

Comment: And I did not change any default Tolerance option ..